# How to scrape youtube video description with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube

I am trying to web scrape a list of YouTube videos and I want to collect each video's YouTube description. However, I am unsuccessful and do not understand why so. Any help is much appreciated. (Youtube video in question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57Tjvv_pCXg&t=55s)

```
element_titles = driver.find_elements_by_id("video-title")
result = requests.get(element_titles[1].get_attribute("href"))
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content)
description = str(soup.find("div", {"class": "style-scope yt-formatted-string"}))
```

The results of the decription is *None*

**Note**
I understand that there exists a Youtube API however you must pay for an API key and it is not in my interest to do so

Comment: you don't have to pay for an API key. at least since I have been using youtube's API https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N18czV5tj5o if you need to get an API key.  instead of using the class to find the element instead use `"id": "description"`

Comment: why don't you use selenium to extract the video description?

Comment: @soundwave How so?

Comment: @AndrewRyan I have tried your suggestion however, it did not work

Comment: @TheBeef can you give us a more reproducible example of what you are doing before this code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the description you can use both selenium or beautifulsoup. The latter is faster, here is the code

```
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57Tjvv_pCXg').content)
pattern = re.compile('(?<=shortDescription":").*(?=","isCrawlable)')
description = pattern.findall(str(soup))[0].replace('\\n','\n')
print(description)
```

If you run `print(soup.prettify())` and look for a part of the video description, say `know this is just my`, you will see that the complete description is inside a big json structure

```
...,"isOwnerViewing":false,"shortDescription":"Listen: https://quellechris360.bandcamp.com/album/deathfame\n\nQuelle Chris delivers what might be his most challengi...bla bla...ABSTRACT HIP HOP\n\n7/10\n\nY'all know this is just my opinion, right?","isCrawlable":true,"thumbnail":{...
```

In particular the description is included between `shortDescription":"` and `","isCrawlable`, so we can use regex to extract the substring included between these two strings. The regex command to find every character (`.*`) included between the two strings is `(?<=shortDescription":").*(?=","isCrawlable)`

Comment: Thank you very very much! Great information